# Access ssl webservice from application deployed on glassfish

Tags: web-services, ssl, glassfish

I want to connet to secure webservice deployed on Microsoft IIS. I'v got a private key and certificate in pkcs12 format from vendor and CA certificate as well. 
I've imported CA certificate to glassfish domain truststore file:
"keytool.exe -import -keystore ./cacerts.jks -trustcacerts -file ./my_vendor_ca.pem"

Also i've imported private key and client certificate to domain keystore file:
"keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass somepassword -alias 1"

But when I trying to connect websrvice, i receiving error from IIS "403.7 - Client certificate required."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I trying to connect websrvice, i receiving error from IIS
>   "403.7 - Client certificate required."

This means that IIS is configured for client authentication and either your client application does not send a certificate (so send certificate to IIS) or your client application sends a certificate but is not configured as trusted by IIS (so add it as trusted in IIS)